# Computing the coefficients of series

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, series-expansion, coefficients

I am trying to fully expand the following
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{(q;q)_n}$$
Which when expressed in Mathematic is: q^(n*(n + 1)/2)/QPochhammer[q, q, n]

I would like to be able to fully expand this series into individual powers of q. This should be a power series, with integer coefficients for each power. How can I get the fully expanded power series? Ultimately, I would like to obtain a list of all the coefficients. Your help will go along way.

Thanks

Comment: _Which when expressed in Mathematic is: q^{n*(n + 1)/2}/QPochhammer[q, q, n]_ No it is not. You are using curly brackets which are for lists and things, not subexpressions. The correct way is `q^(n(n+1)/2)/QPochhammer[q, q, n]`

Comment: Ah, you are right. But this does not solve my problem. Can you help me?

Comment: You say you want all of the coefficients. I don't know if that is possible. If you want all of the coefficients up to say `q^55`, that is easy.

Comment: @Carl Woll Yes, this would be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a weakness in series expansions of [`QPochhammer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer) in Mathematica:

```
Series[QPochhammer[q, q, 2], {q, 0, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $1+q
>    \left(\text{QPochhammer}^{(0,1,0)}(0,0,2)+\text{QPochhammer}^{(1,0,0)}(0,0,2)\right)+O
>    \left(q^2\right)$

You can fix this by using [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand) (essentially Vaclav Kotesovec's comment to Bill Watt's answer):

```
Series[FunctionExpand @ QPochhammer[q, q, 2], {q, 0, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $1-q+O\left(q^2\right)$

So, the following should produce your desired result:

```
ser[k_] := With[{m = Ceiling[1/2 (-1+Sqrt[1+8 k])]},
    Series[
        Sum[q^(n (n+1)/2) / FunctionExpand @ QPochhammer[q, q, n], {n, 0, m}],
        {q, 0, k}
    ]
]
```

Example:

```
ser[20] //TeXForm
```

> $1+q+q^2+2 q^3+2 q^4+3 q^5+4 q^6+5 q^7+6 q^8+8 q^9+10 q^{10}+12 q^{11}+15 q^{12}+18
>    q^{13}+22 q^{14}+27 q^{15}+32 q^{16}+38 q^{17}+46 q^{18}+54 q^{19}+64
>    q^{20}+O\left(q^{21}\right)$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get all the terms, but if you want to look at a finite number you can do something like this:

First get a series in `q` from

```
fn = q^(1/2 n (n + 1))/QPochhammer[q, q, n]

Series[fn, {q, 0, 100}] // Normal
```

Then apply the first few `n`

```
Plus @@ (Table[%, {n, 0, 100}] // Expand)
```

That should give you several coefficients to play with.  If you want more, you can make the `Series` and `Table` longer if you have the computing power.

Comment: When I implement this, I don't get the coefficients. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Use `n = 10; Series[Sum[q^(k*(k+1)/2)/Product[(1 - q^j), {j, 1, k}], {k, 0, n}], {q, 0, n}]`

Comment: This is also sequence A000009 in the OEIS.

Comment: You should get a series in powers of $q$.  What are you getting instead?

Comment: In general should I use the product command, as opposed to QPochhammer?

Comment: @BillWatts, I was getting the value 1

Comment: I get a series in q. V12.0.0